# Database to Production

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I'm developing a web api with Entity Framework. I tried publishing the api with the database to the production server via web deploy (VS). I checked the "Code First Migrations" checkbox in the web deploy assistant but the database isn't created.

How do I handle this?

The publishing profile looks like this:

```
<PublishDatabaseSettings>
  <Objects xmlns="">
    <ObjectGroup Name="DBNAME_DB" Order="1" Enabled="True">
      <Destination Path="Data Source=server;Initial      Catalog=DBNAME_DB;Integrated Security=True" />
      <Object Type="DbCodeFirst">
        <Source Path="DBMigration" DbContext="ALC.Server.Database.DatabaseContext, ALC.Server.Database" MigrationConfiguration="ALC.Server.Database.Migrations.Configuration, ALC.Server.Database" Origin="Configuration" />
      </Object>
    </ObjectGroup>
  </Objects>
</PublishDatabaseSettings>
```

**SOLUTION**:

Found the problem - the application pool identity was no `dbcreator` on the SQL Server....

Comment: Do you have any error when the site is starting?

Comment: Do you have an error?

Comment: its an web api. When i access it it returns null from all controllers, but i think this is because the database doesnt exists?

Comment: found the problem - the application Pool Identity was no dbcreator on the sql server....

Comment: Please Edit your question and add your last comment about this issue.